# Exponential formula with decreasing multiplication factor

Tags: geometric-series, exponential-sum

I am attempting to simply the following calculation where the initial number is $2.4$ and add a decrease of $10$% from the previous step:

$1.$ $2.4\times 0.9 = 2.16$

$2.$ $2.4\times\left(0.9 + {0.9}^2\right) = 4.104$

$3.$ $2.4\times\left(0.9 + {0.9}^2 + {0.9}^3\right) = 5.8536$

$4.$ $2.4\times\left(0.9 + {0.9}^2 + {0.9}^3 + {0.9}^4\right) = 7.42824$

$5.$ $2.4\times\left(0.9 + {0.9}^2 + {0.9}^3 + {0.9}^4 + {0.9}^5\right) = 8.845416$

$\dots$ and so on

How could I simply this pattern when the number of adding is X?

Comment: It is *very* unclear what the question is

Comment: trying to create a formula where the increasing number of additional power ofs added on is X

Comment: This is a simple application of a finite geometric series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a hint, consider the geometric series $$a(1+q+q^2+\ldots+q^{n-1}) = a\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}.$$